# Como customizar o marcador de localização atual(GPS) no Maps api v2 android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Bem pessoal quero customizar o pontinho azul do gps no Maps e quero que eu possa mexê-lo para qualquer lugar do mapa, bem como funciona nos aplicativos de Táxi..

Comment: Sua pergunta é "como adicionar o marker" ou "como customizar o pontinho azul"?

Comment: Customizar o pontinho azul

Comment: Acho que seria melhor você [edit] também o título da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Para alterar o ícone azul padrão que define a localização do usuário no seu mapa, primeiro você precisa desabilitar a busca automática desta localização que é feita com o método [`setMyLocationEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29). Então faça o seguinte primeiramente:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

E também, considerando que você não utilize algum mecanismo de *"traker"*, eu tenho uma classe assim, que adiciono dentro da minha *Activity*:

```
private class BuscarCoordenadasTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private Location userLocation;

        private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                userLocation = location;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0.0f, locationListener);
                }

                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0.0f, locationListener);
                }
            } else {
                // Nenhum provedor de localização, cancela requisição
                cancel(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while (userLocation == null) {}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

            // Adiciona localização do usuário no mapa, com novo ícone
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_meu_local)));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
}
```

Em resumo, a classe que estende de `AsyncTask` para fazer uma chamada em segundo plano irá buscar a localização do usuário pelo provedor de GPS (`GPS_PROVIDER`) e também pela rede (`NETWORK_PROVIDER`), o que estiver disponível e que vier primeiro.

Assim que encontrar, no `onPostExecute` é que o novo marcador vai ser adicionado ao seu mapa e o *listener* de localização será cancelado. Se desejar que a cada atualização da localização do usuário o marcador vá "andando", como um *tracker*, você vai precisar manter sempre *escutando* e ir removendo o marcador para adicionar um novo com as novas coordenadas.

E por fim, na sua *Activity* tem a chamada:

```
BuscarCoordenadasTask task = new BuscarCoordenadasTask();
task.execute();
```